# Reset settings.json in Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, settings, reset

I am new to Visual Studio Code trying to learn Python. I was watching videos to edit the settings and I must have messed something up because when trying to run in debug, an error comes up: "Configured debug type 'python' is not supported." with an option to open up the settings.

I'm running my program in "Python: Current File" configuration, but none of the other configurations work either.

I'd just like to reset to default so I can try again.

Thanks in advance!